TonStakers Liquid STaking Protocol
I want to create stake and unstake transaction object using nodejs which accepts the wallet address and amount to be staked, how to do this?
I want to create stake and unstake prepared transaction object/payload. Only require prepared not signed transaction so no required private key.

Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please show some attempts of yours and ask a more specific question. Otherwise, this sounds as "code this for me", which is not on-topic on SO.
